# How do i generate a list of all tuples in element R in haskel

Tags: haskell, haskell-platform

I just cant find a way to generate tuples in element R like (1,2) Thats should make <1,1>,<1,2><2,1><2,2>

Comment: Sorry, what exactly is `R` in this context?

Comment: Better expained i have 
x={1,2}
y={1,2}
And i want to generate tuples from my list X*Y

Comment: There is a well known functional pearl for generating an infinite tree of (provably) every rational number, lazily: https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/ralf.hinze/publications/Bird.pdf. As it mentions, there's also the [Stern–Brocot tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern–Brocot_tree) and [Calkin-Wilf tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calkin–Wilf_tree)

Answer (score 3):

The shortest and most convenient way to take two lists `x` and `y` and generate tuples from them is

```
liftM2 (,) x y
```

The most self-explanatory way to do this is

```
[(a, b) | a <- x, b <- y]
```